# ng-view won't display template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-view, route-provider

I have been working a bit with Angular and I tried to implement simple routing. 
I have a basic HTML which contains reference to all the required scripts and a `ng-view` tag.

For some reason, when the page is loaded, the template isn't shown in the `ng-view` location. Why isn't it shown, and how to fix it?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="routCtrl.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app='ngRouteTest'>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

and the the script file:

```
var ngRouteTest = angular.module('ngRouteTest',['ngRoute']);
ngRouteTest.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
.when('/', 
     {templateUrl : '/routView1.html'})
});
```

Comment: What does the developer console say ? Any errors/warnings ?

Comment: The following error: "Failed to load template".

Comment: Then the problem is that you are providing a wrong path to the html file. where is your routView1.html ? What does your folder structure look like ?

Comment: I have all the files located in the same folder (I don't believe that the path is the issue).
I think the problem is with the ajax call resulted from the routing and the fact that it is a security issue if it's preformed locally in chrome.

Comment: There should be more than just "failed to load template". The dev tools usually also mention which path was requested... can you post a screenshot of you console ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay first you need to run your code from a server, so to test it locally use [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) which is really easy to prepare.

Then you will need to change your templateUrl path from:

```
{templateUrl : '/routView1.html'}
```

to:

```
{templateUrl : './routView1.html'}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to redirect to that page so that routing will come to know which page to render inside `ng-view` directive.

There are multiple ways to do it.

1. Define one more otherwise to redirect to `/`.

   ```
   $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'})
   ```
2. Add anchor to page that will redirect to `/`.

   ```
   <body ng-app='ngRouteTest'>
       <a href="#/">Home Page</a>
       <div ng-view></div>
   </body>
   ```
3. Having default url on page in `<head>` tag.

   ```
   <base href="/"/>
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, none of the options helped.
I do see the routing preformed after adding the "otherwise" but the ng-view doesn't load the template. 
Going to the console as asked above i see the following error:
"Failed to load template".
I presume the problem is that the files are stored locally and result in security issues -  i will start a server and see if i get a different result.

Answer (score 0):

After starting a local host and ruining the code from there it worked perfectly fine.

The issue was with the chrome related security when you make local ajax calls.

So one has this problem should do one of the following things:

1.Disable web-security in chrome.
2.Start a local host to test.